# Can't get concurrent calls to WCF web service to work

Tags: wcf, concurrency

I've got a WCF web service, as a test it contains a method which calls a stored procedure which waits for 10 seconds then returns.

I have a test program which starts 20 threads all calling this web service method at the same time. The result I get is two calls return in 10 seconds, then 10 seconds later another two calls return, and so on. So the web service is processing the calls only two at a time.

Now the simple answer may be to change ConcurrencyMode to Multiple, and maybe change the throttling settings, but when I do this it doesn't have any effect.

The web service is hosted on IIS 7.5. Currently all the settings are as default, although as I said I've tried setting ConcurrencyMode to Multiple.

If anyone can help me with this I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you share a sample app that repros the problem? Unfortunately in WCF there are a zillion config knobs that it could be, so knowing which ones you have already tweaked as well as how you're using WCF (what bindings, etc.) would be helpful.

Comment: How loaded is your server?  Maybe it can only execute two threads at a time in it's current state?  Could be that your application is only executing two threads at a time on the client side?  Have you tried to run the app on multiple clients at the same time to see if it is really the server, or if it is the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the maxconnection from the default (2) to a larger value in your caller's config file.

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="10" />
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```